# HDDs are scratching at IDLE state on mdadm RAID 5

Tags: raid, mdadm, nas, raid5

I have a mdadm RAID 5 on 6 hard drives.

Every one second, I ear the same noisy pattern on hard drives, like when you read/write something on it, but without any operations...

The raid is clean and no process are writing on it (logs or things like that.)

I tried

```
root@pandaria:/# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Sep 21 13:52:55 2021
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 39069470720 (37259.55 GiB 40007.14 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894144 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Oct  2 20:06:32 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 6
   Working Devices : 6
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : 043182bc:857ef2ce:d2251586:88cb5e32
            Events : 73301

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       2       8       32        2      active sync   /dev/sdc
       4       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
       6       8       80        4      active sync   /dev/sdf
       5       8       64        5      active sync   /dev/sde


root@pandaria:/# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdd[4] sda[0] sdc[2] sdf[6] sdb[1] sde[5]
      39069470720 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 2/59 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Any ideas why a hard drive is reading/writing ?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Test all disks individually which one is scratching, it is on its last leg.

Comment: Why do you mean by "on it's last leg" ?

Comment: @jsotola, Why does a hard drive scatch all the time ? How can I know what is does all the time ? Is it a failure problem ? How can I diagnose ?